# array return empty when call it out of own method

Tags: arrays, swift

i am making a url call with alamofire to GET data as below . when i print variables inside the call method its show correctly but when i call that out side the method , like View dIdLoad or some where there no value inside array and print empty  [ ] .

```
    class ChartVC: UIViewController {

        var _year : [String] = []
        var _month : [String] = []
        var _price : [String] = []

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

         getData()
   // show empty array 
            print(_month)
        }

        func getData() {

            AF.request(DOLLAR_CHART).response { (response) in
                guard let data = response.data else { return }
                let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let items = responseJSON as? [[String: Any]] {
                    var years: [String] = []
                    var months: [String] = []
                    var prices: [String] = []
                    for item in items {
                        if let year =  item["year"] as? String  {
                            years.append(year)


                        }
                        if let month = item["month"] as? String {
                            months.append(month)
                        }
                        if let price = item["price"] as? String{
                            prices.append(price)

                        }

                    }

                    self._year = years
                    self._month = months
                    self._price = prices
                    //print correctly
                    print(_months)


                } else {
                    print("json is not array dictionary")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do some searching on "asynchronous".

Answer (score 0):

You are adding data after the network calls completed. It will print data everytime once your call is completed. At the time of did load the initial data (which is empty intialization in your case) will be printed.

If you want to do any UI updates then do updtae after your call is completed.

Comment: @mehrankmlf take look at alxlives's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57489082/2677551

Answer (score 0):

This is because the request takes a while to receive the answer, and your `print(_month)` in the `viewDidLoad()` method is executed before the answer from the service.

You need to wait for the service to return, parse the response and only then use the data.

A good approach would be this:

```swift
   self._year = years
   self._month = months
   self._price = prices
   //print correctly
   self.updateUI()
```

```swift
func updateUI() {
   //Use response
}
```

EDIT - Full code

```swift
    class ChartVC: UIViewController {

        var _year : [String] = []
        var _month : [String] = []
        var _price : [String] = []

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            getData()
        }

        func getData() {

            AF.request(DOLLAR_CHART).response { (response) in
                guard let data = response.data else { return }
                let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let items = responseJSON as? [[String: Any]] {
                    var years: [String] = []
                    var months: [String] = []
                    var prices: [String] = []
                    for item in items {
                        if let year =  item["year"] as? String  {
                            years.append(year)
                       }
                        if let month = item["month"] as? String {
                            months.append(month)
                        }
                        if let price = item["price"] as? String{
                            prices.append(price)
                        }

                    }

                    self._year = years
                    self._month = months
                    self._price = prices
                    self.updateUI()

                } else {
                    print("json is not array dictionary")
                }
            }
        }

        func updateUI() {
           //USE THE RESPONSE AND UPDATE THE UI HERE
        }
```

Comment: Sure, one moment

Comment: tnx for your answer bro but really i cant understand what should i do in updateUI() method

Comment: Use the arrays. If you print _month, _price or _year inside the function they will have data